# How does one prove one has sufficient funds for one's period of stay in Myanmar when entering with an e-visa?

Tags: proof-provenance-of-funds, e-visas, myanmar

I read on the e-visa for Myanmar:

[image]

How does one prove one has sufficient funds for one's period of stay in Myanmar when entering with an e-visa?

Answer (score 3):

There are variety of ways to show proof of funds.

- Have the actual cash in hand.
- Copy of pass book or statement in bank.
- ATM slip showing the balance.
- Letter from your sponsor in the country you are visiting, if the trip is sponsored by someone.

Usually, most countries won't ask in border checks, unless they get suspicious.

Note: Some countries need a minimum amount, for example Thailand when I entered asked me a proof for 20k Thai Bhat, even though I was only there for two days. Malaysia on the other hand didn't ask for umpteen number of times I visited.

Comment: As per as your pic, no. Just well enough amount for your stay and expenses is ok.